# Record not found despite being present

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.4

well I'm post data json to my backend and I have this error:

```
{
  "message": "Record not found in table \"users\" with primary key ['6']",
  "url": "/users/userdata",
  "code": 404
}
```

I don't know why? I have a user with id = 6 in my database, in my function I recieve the data and id correctly, check this part, my controller:

```
  public function userdata()
    {
        $user = TableRegistry::get('Users');
        $id = $this->request->getData('iduser');

        $data = $user->get($id, [
            //'contain' => ['Cities']
        ]);

        $this->set([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $data,
            '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']
        ]);
    }
```

[image: posting data]

Try this with `$this->Users->get($id)` and `$this->Users->find($id)` I always get the same error

Comment: will you please debug `$id` before `get()` query, and check the value

Comment: I already did this the value I get is 6

Comment: what is type of this `$id` its `int` , `string` or `array` ?

Comment: I thought about this before so I tried to convert to int the data I received a
 string ´$data = (int)$id;´ of this way I tried to convert to int and not work

Comment: `['6']` looks like array, that's why asking the actual type of `$id`

Comment: I send this format of json { "iduser": 6 } and try with this too { "iduser": "6" } , [6] and ['6'] even if I transform to int this not  work,

Comment: is_array($id); is false when I debug this

Comment: Post the javascript.  You could $id = (int) $this->request->getData('iduser');  to make sure it isn't a type issue

Comment: I'm using postman for test. I did not javascript first created the backend after i do the frontend

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message can be a little bit misleading, as one could think that it's really about trying to access something in the database, however it's actually a `InvalidPrimaryKeyException` exception (whenever receiving errors, check the logs!).

This happens when the passed primary key format doesn't match the primary key configuration of the table, like for example when the primary key is a composite key, and you're not passing all required columns. It could also happen in case the tables primary key is wrongly configured, for example when it's empty.

Make sure that you're passing all required columns, check your tables `setPrimaryKey()`/`primaryKey()` call, make sure to clear the mode cache (`tmp/cache/models`) to avoid wrong/old schemas to be used, and ensure that the primary key constraint in the database is configured properly.